# How to write xpath for the 'Submit' button?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is the html code when I inspected the 'Submit' button. When I inspected with firebug, it came like this,

```
.//*[@id='step-content-2']/div/md-step-actions/button[2]
```

But the @id='step-content-2' keeps on varying which is difficult for me to find the right xpath

Below is the inspect element code when i clicked the 'submit' button

```
<button class="md-primary md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="submit()">
   <span>                             Submit                         </span>
   <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I also have the same type button for 'Cancel'. Is it possible to create a function in such a way that it can be used for both cancle and submit buttons ?

Comment: Yes. You can write a method. You need to parameterize the xpath and pass the varying text as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath for clicking the submit button:

`//span[normalize-space()='Submit']/parent::button`

This XPath will always be unique.